# What to do when other committers don't care about your proposed changes?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

I am one of the committer of [Sqoop](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqoop/topics) Documentation. I added a new [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/36734) in Sqoop tag before 4 days.

It's status is **Awaiting approval**.

What should I do when other committers don't care about your proposed changes and they don't have any say- Good or Bad?

Comment: Basically, you are one of those low traffic tags.

Comment: @Braiam I guess every tag has 5 commiters.

Comment: But if your fellow commiters don't participate...

Comment: @Braiam that's the problem. It demotivates me to write more examples..:(

Comment: You could try to invite others to chat and ask that they approve. There's [a chat for JavaScript documentation](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118002/javascript-documentation-discussion), for instance. The trick is, of course, to get committers to go along with you...

Comment: "Sqoop" is the best name ever for a technology. I can't help but laugh xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably gonna want to be a little bit patient. [As I mentioned over yonder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329530/commiters-to-a-tag-should-have-notifications-enabled-by-default), only half of the other committers have even read the message noting that you've proposed changes... It might be a little while before the others show up.

If, after a day or two, you're *still* waiting, you might try to drum up some interest elsewhere where Sqoop folks congregate.

Eventually, we're probably gonna want some sort of review interface to ensure these proposals don't fall through the cracks. Alternately, requiring more people to commit to a tag would likely help with this problem as well.

Comment: Hi Shog9, I did not get  - _you might try to drum up some interest elsewhere where Sqoop folks congregate._ Here elsewhere means outside SO?

Comment: Probably? I know nothing about Sqoop I'm afraid.