# Commiters to a tag should have notifications enabled by default

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, notifications

[This is sad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329520/792066). As for me personally I feel courage. Why would you commit to a tag just to abandon it, leaving your fellow commiters? I don't think that should be accepted. For that I propose this change:

- Commiters have enabled notifications for Improvement Requests, Proposed Changes and Requested Topics.
- This cannot be disabled until a month passes.

It should be pretty obvious that commitment is serious business, and commiters have a responsibility with their fellows commiters.

Comment: *This cannot be disabled until a month passes.* I see where you're coming from, but that won't fly. External circumstances may very well require users to throttle back their participation for a while. We cannot force them to either leave the site completely or endure the notifications for one month.

Comment: We do item one already. (I should know because I committed to a bunch of tags before launch and got slammed with notifications.) Item the second? Um. I see where you are coming from, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi err... [documentation has just 3 days out and you suddenly can't participate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329520/what-to-do-when-other-committers-dont-care-about-your-proposed-changes#comment372985_329520)

Comment: @Braiam, they *can* participate, they just aren't in the right tag. Like playing Pokémon Go in Toronto. However, from what I heard of what's happening in the more popular tags, they're not missing much.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi is the other side of the coin, sadly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, that "can't disable for a month" thing is crazy; we're not gonna do that.

But the other bit already exists. In fact, four people currently have notifications sitting in their inboxes informing them of the proposed changes in that Sqoop tag. Two of them have even *read* those notifications. If they haven't done anything about it yet, that's their business.

So marking this completed.

Comment: You need the stick too, Shog. [Carrot alone doesn't do the job.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329459/792066)

Comment: "if you get busy we're going to make notifications unbearably noisy" is a hell of a stick.

Comment: @Shog9 Sounds like the perfect stick to me! That is, if you're using it for beatings rather than holding a carrot. Might get heavy if you're using it for the carrot...

Comment: Someone could argue that you are giving away a hell of a carrot. Anyways, can you document exactly how this happen, I had no idea it even happened.

Comment: The "carrot" here is... Pretty much also just the promise of craploads of notifications. So...