# Add a tag-reputation limit on Documentation reviews

Tags: feature-request, documentation

10 minutes ago the jQuery Selectors page within Documentation [had its Introduction changed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/130898?filter-tags=jquery) to:

> A jQuery selectors selects or finds a DOM (document object model) element in an HTML document. It is used to select HTML elements based on id, name, types, attributes, class and etc. It is based on existing CSS selectors.

Ignoring the obvious grammar mistakes, it's completely misleading, however it was almost immediately approved (under 15 minutes) by three users with essentially no [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) contributions here on Stack Overflow.

- The first user has 155 reputation and has not posted a single jQuery-tagged question or answer.
- The second user has just over 2,000 reputation and has two questions and one answer tagged with jQuery; only one of these questions has a single upvote (oh, and they were all from 2011).
- The third user has 798 reputation and has two questions and two answers tagged with jQuery with a grand total of 1 upvote (which I've now removed from them as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066530/controlling-styles-in-knockoutjs-based-on-the-values/37066728#37066728) had nothing to do with jQuery).

Can we please add some sort of tag-based reputation restriction on reviewing documentation content?

Comment: Is there a reason we're closing `feature-request` questions as duplicates of `discussion` questions? Seems like they can't be duplicates if one is asking for a feature and the other is asking for general discussion...

Comment: There's no rollback reason for "poor quality", and the description of what jquery selectors are in the api docs is far better than anything i can come up with, so... what do you do with this? choose other and just remove it?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what that restriction would look like? And keep in mind... Just because I don't have answers in, say, regex doesn't mean I don't know what I'm talking about a fair amount of time. I find it incredibly hard to answer in regex, because an incredible number of the questions there when I try are either in need of closure, or already more than satisfactorily answered. (TL;DR: Tag rep doesn't indicate someone who wouldn't do this, and lack of tag rep doesn't mean someone is immediately not going to review well.)

Comment: bump the rep requirement to 500 like everything else. It won't make the situation impossible to happen, but atleast it'l block out some of the incorrect reviews.

Comment: I don't think tag-based really works for restricting people from something like this. Not all edits require domain knowledge to review changes, and quite a few tags simply don't have enough people with said tag badges to review them. All we really can do is get more people who would do it correctly interested in doing it, and/or making it harder/less rewarding for others to do it.

Comment: @Kendra SO does already prevent people from requesting tag synonyms if they don't have enough of a score in the given tag, so a similar system is already in place.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I would argue that this would be different. For tag synonyms, a user with insufficient tag score can just come to Meta and make their case. Reviews happen much faster, _and_ the reviewer doesn't trigger the review, they vote on it. In this case, a user with insufficient tag score would _not_ be able to bring these to Meta, as they would not be able to get into the review queue to bring up reviews they wanted assistance approving/rejecting. I agree with Kevin, I don't this works for this case. I'd prefer raising the minimum rep to review in this queue.

Comment: I'm curious, what's a correct intro for this tag? I'm not a jQuery selector guru myself, but this intro looks fine, especially if there was no intro before, like in this case.

Comment: Suggest something specific. Min 500 rep total and 250 in that tag? Or what?

Comment: @justhalf aside from the grammar issues it seems mostly fine, I'd just prefer it be more clear that a jquery selector is just a string that is passed as an argument to `$()`. `$()` itself isn't a selector.

Comment: I believe this has already been proposed, and rejected because all this "everyone must be able to contribute" thing (thing is not the two words I have in mind right now), but maybe we could prevent people with no experience whatsoever in a tag to propose changes? a bronze badge seems like a fine way to know if womeone knows enough about a topic to actually say something that makes sense. In this case it would have prevented this situation to happen.

Comment: See also numerous other questions, such as [Bogus documentation item approved — can it be prevented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336271/) and (more relevantly) [Should people who've never asked or answered a question for C be allowed to review C documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339137/) and multiple others.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, bronze tag..How are they going to get a bronze tag on low tag! With an average of 2 question a day and one up vote an one answer every 2 days!

Comment: @PierreLebon They won't, which is exactly the point, add will let us write proper documentation ;)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, so niche tag will never documentation edit? Take for exemple [tag:telerik], 8,208 question and 1 bronze badge. You need ~+200 answer to get a bronze badge with 5 question per days, That's 40 day. Take a no mans land tag like Mit-scratch and comes back with the math.

Comment: I'am not against the idea, but it's not doable for niche tag. Therefor it's not doable.

Comment: @PierreLebon that have been mentioned countless times, and sounds right in theory, bit I wonder, in practice, how many tags would be affected. Also, it's possible to search for a solution and its variations more than 0.5 seconds don't you think?

Comment: @PierreLebon btw your stats are completely off. Bronze badge is a score of 100 on 20 answers. Would you care to source that 5 questions per day stuff? Also, we can very easily conceive allowing people with 2k rep propose documentation changes on any tags, to prevent niche tags from never being documented.

Comment: I just read the title, nothing more, and upvoted.

Answer (score 17):

I do agree that the bar reviewing documentation is too low. However, I think using tagscore based criterias are going to cause more problems than it solves.

The whole purpose of adding the review queue for documentation was to allow more  people to review it. Before the review queue, only people who were interested in a specific tag's documentation were reviewing suggested edits and the queue was backing up and out of control. If we were to limit the review queue to only those who have a tag badge, we'd be in a similar (although better) situation in that the pool of potential reviewers for each edit would be considerably reduced, even moreso for lesser-visited tags, possibly to the point where the queue gets out of control again for any tag not in the top 20.

I think a step in the right direction would be to start by increasing the rep requirement from 100 rep to 500 rep to bring this queue in line with the other review queues. I would argue though that reviewing edits to documentation is even harder than reviewing edits to questions/answers due to the fact that some of the edits do require domain knowledge to properly review them, so maybe the bar should be even higher, or possibly provide more guidance to the reviewer so that the reviewer knows they need to police themselves to ensure they're only reviewing edits that they have the domain knowledge to do so effectively.

Comment: I would suggest that people having a gold/silver badge related to that specific tag alone should be allowed to modify and review documentation for that particular tag. Do **not** allow anyone /everyone to review anything/everything

Comment: @JeruLuke There are many, many tags with only a couple of gold badge owners, some tags even have no gold badges at all. This would mean that those tags cannot be reviewed.

Comment: Hmm I get it. Another thing that leads to such hasty reviews is the want to get the **Reviewer** badge

Comment: @usr1234567 well, how about if we simply bump the eligible criteria to be allowed to create a documentation tag: instead of 5 users with 1 score and 500 questions, 5 users with 50 tag score and 1k questions.

Comment: *"some of the edits do require domain knowledge to properly review them"*, Isn't that what a tag score would imply? *"Before the review queue, only people who were interested in a specific tag's documentation were reviewing suggested edits and the queue was backing up and out of control."*, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I mean, i'd rather documentation to get the axe tbh, but at the same time basing it on tag score would only work for the top n tags, for any of the others (the tags that could actually benefit from additional examples/documentation) there won't be enough people reviewing.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt it was [partially my fault](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329530/792066), but my solution implied that committers fulfill their commitment for the tag or the tag just go back to 0.

Comment: @KevinB _there won't be enough people reviewing_ -- But are the tags outside the top _n_ suffering from not enough reviewers? Or are they suffering from a lack of people with the necessary domain knowledge to participate -- create and review content? If the latter, then allowing anyone to review doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Currently, they are not due to the fact that it is wide open. Before the review queue, even jquery, which DOES have a lot of followers, had a very large backlog of edits/additions not being reviewed.

Comment: @KevinB Point taken. Another question: let's say the required minimum score in the tag would not be fixed at some value for all tags, but rather would be tied to some global metric -- e.g. total score of tag in all questions for all users relative to the total score of all questions, or something similar. Would this help?

Comment: Depending on the metric, possibly. Here's a list of bronze badges and how many people have obtained them: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze A bronze badge requires a tag score of 100 from at least 20 non-wiki answers.

Comment: Taking that list, and picking a tag off the front page of documentation [tag:vim], there's currently 147 users who have a bronze badge in [tag:vim]. [tag:node.js] has 444. Of course, only a small percentage of those users likely use the review queues or even participate in documentation at all. I've been developing with coldfusion for almost 9 years, and don't have a bronze badge in coldfusion.

Comment: Here's the delimma. A lot of these lower traffic tags are related to some more popular tag. Node.js, jquery, angular, react, etc examples can be adequately reviewed by javascript users. but not all javascript users have tag scores in those other tags.

Comment: Maybe we should use a system where each review is weighted based on the reviewer's knowledge of the topic.  If you have 0 tag score your review counts for one point (to alleviate the issue you mentioned); additional points are given based on the reviewer's tag score: +2 points per badge (i.e. at 100, 400, and 1000 tag score), and +1 if you're halfway to your next badge, where gold's "next badge" is at 4000 (10x silver's score) to parallel gold being at 10x bronze's score.  An item would need 8 points to leave the queue, so one person with the max score can singlehandedly decide.

Comment: If this is too slow for some tags, then maybe badges in related tags can count as +1 each (e.g. gold JavaScript counting as +3 towards Node.js, JQuery, Angular, etc., to use Kevin B's example).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, please.

On the main site, reviewing (edits) requires 2'000 reputation. As documentation is supposed to be composed by experts, having requirements any lower than these seems entirely unreasonable to me.

I do like the idea of *some* tag-affinity for reviewing requirements, but I do not like the idea of tag *badges* because IMO they set the bar way too high for low traffic tags, preventing documentation for a lot of them to be reviewed at all.

I propose a requirement that is based **a little** on tags, but **mostly on reputation**.

I'm open for the exact numbers, but consider:

> To review documentation edits for tag X, a user must have at least:
>
> - 2'000 overall reputation
> - 10 positively-scored answers in tag X

Answer (score 3):

I support this Feature Request*.

Documentation is meant to be a set of examples. It is not meant to replace existing documentation with pages of sentences.

Reviewing examples requires domain knowledge. Domain knowledge is measured in tag-score (not perfect, but a start).

A general (global) reputation cap says nothing. Does Jon Skeet have knowlege in [`[google-bigquery]`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=88)?

<sub>*Maybe exclude low traffic tags</sub>

---

There is some discussion about bronze badges that are rare; that is irrelevant. We are talking about x score. Nobody says x must be 100. Imho, something like 5/10 well received answers would also be OK.

There is also a discussion, that every `[javascript]` developer is able to review `[jquery]`. That is the same assumption as, say, every `[c#]` developer is able to review `[entity-framework]`. It would be true for many people, but those people would also have a score in the more specific tag.

---

Ask yourself:

Do you want another H&I-queue, where 95% is skipped, or do you want a queue where you can always take an appropriate action?