# Allow "low activity tag" into documentation by community vote

Tags: feature-request, documentation

**edit** As to the duplicate tag. This is not a question for clarification. This is a feature request. For something to add to it, to allow thresholds to be also be influenced by the community in niche cases.

---

If a tag is low activity/not at the 500 questions threshold (like [minecraft-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge)), but there are people enthusiastic about writing documentation about it, allow a an "application" procedure for that tag to be included in documentation.

A person who wishes to write documentation for it could write his explanation why he wishes to start the tag, what his perceived benefit is, etc...

Then it could be reviewed by community members and if 10 members state looks ok, it can be added as a tag for documentation.

The tag minecraft-forge could really benefit from the format and exposure stackoverflow gives, but I really don't feel like asking another 350 questions just to get at the 500 treshold before I can write documentation.

I'd like to be able to apply for it to go through, and give people a neat and uniform way of documenting it, instead of how splintered and unmanaged it is right now on the internet.

I can imagine that there are other communities/tags that are relatively "obscure" because the main devs are more involved with coding than writing documentation, but there are community members who wish to contribute in a single unified source, where all relevant links can be provided on the same site instead of splintered and half explained on the various (outdated/abandoned) sites online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "This tag is too new, or too low activity, for Documentation to be created for it"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328419/error-this-tag-is-too-new-or-too-low-activity-for-documentation-to-be-created)

Comment: The answer may be found in the possible duplicate: "*that's the requirement for now. Keep in mind that this is a **beta***".

Comment: And SO developers have probably enough work on fixing the current problems of Documentation before having to think about a new review queue.

Comment: @A.L As to a feature request it does not have to be added right now, can be done in the feature, but if nobody ask's for it under feature-request, they do not have a handy list to sort it under. Also, this gives the community chance to weigh in if they think this is a feature that should be added by voting on this featurerequest

Comment: Docs already suffers from [long approval times](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329462/contribution-to-documentation-low-engagement-levels-high-approval-turn-aroun), lasting for days in [low-traffic tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329520/4151918). If the [tag:minecraft-forge] tag is low-activity, how will you find enough people to continually review any doc submissions?

Answer (score 1):

The [email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329022/6083675) that Gary Ewan Park got from the Stack Overflow team explains that this is most likely [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred):

> > A tag does require at least 500 questions to have been asked with it before it can be proposed in the new Documentation beta. This restriction may change in the future, but that's the requirement for now. Keep in mind that this is a *beta* and the idea here is to get a grasp on how it's working with more popular languages before it expands into a full feature.

(My suggestion is to work on the content for those smaller Documentation tags now, so that when this happens, you'll be prepared.)